# Forwarded Email getting associated with same Case, instead of creating a new case

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have noticed that forwarded email from a different sender for an existing case if there a case already exists in the system, is getting associated with the same case instead of creating a new case in the queue.

Explaining the Scenario:
1. I have configured a mailbox and 'Dummy' Queue for email address say: dummy@mycompanydomain.com
2. Case Creation rule is configured for any email coming to this queue.

Sending Emails in 2 different scenarios:

1. Sent email from ABC@outlook.com

TO :  DEF@outlook.com & XYZ@outlook.com

"Replied to All" from DEF@outlook.com to ABD@outlook.com, XYZ@outlook.com and Added dummy@mycompanydomain.com email address as well.

```
     New Ticket got created in 'Dummy' queue.  – Working as expected.
```

"Replied to All" from XYZ to ABD, DEF and Added dummy@mycompanydomain.com mailbox as well.

```
     New Ticket got created in ‘'Dummy' queue. – Working as expected.
```

2. Sent email from ABC@outlook.com

TO :  DEF@outlook.com & XYZ@outlook.com

Replied to All from DEF to ABD@outlook.com, XYZ@outlook.com and Added dummy@mycompanydomain.com email address as well.

```
    New Ticket got created in "Dummy" queue.  – Working as expected.
```

Forwarded from XYZ to dymmy@mycompanydomain.com mailbox.

```
    Incoming Email got associated with existing Ticket in ‘Dummy’ queue. -- Is this an expected behavior or a product bug?
```

Incoming Email got associated with existing Ticket in ‘Dummy’ queue. -- Is this an expected behavior or a product bug?

Comment: I would recommend you to call MS Support for a ticket to understand the expected behavior, then they will test in their sandbox, confirm with PG team to update you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware of the type of matching you are doing in you SSS. If the matching is via regular expression or token a forwarded email will result in a matching Subject.